# Capitals in URL subdirectory not changed by htaccess

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, url, mod-rewrite, authentication

Within my WordPress website I am redirecting sub directories to internal and external links. Now, when you place a CAPITAL letter in the sub dir it does not work anymore and the website does not show the same page.

- `www.mydomain.com/login/` does work properly
- `www.mydomain.com/Login/` does not work properly

I'am using the following in the `.htaccess` file:

```
# Rewrite DE Domain
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.de$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/+subdir/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com/%{REQUEST_URI}?lang=de [L,R=302,NC]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# EXTERNAL Redirects
Redirect /login http://
Redirect /Login https://
```

Comment: Please make your question more clear.... as at the moment its not very constructive even after I've edited it.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work _properly_"? What server/OS are you running? What is `Redirect /login http://` (have you truncated this in the example)?!

Answer (score 1):

Given the .htaccess file you posted, `Login` will never redirect to `login` because the WordPress-specific rules above it contain the `L` flag which stops processing rewrites once evaluated.  So users attempting to go to `Login` are instead redirected to the 404 page by WordPress.